# Notificación sonora de cada solicitud realizada por el sitio

Tags: php

Tengo un sistema de comercio electrónico y me gustaría que cada nuevo pedido, el sistema emitiera un sonido.Para esto creé una tarea cron en el servidor que se ejecutará cada 1 minuto, dirigiendo a la página de notificacion.php.

```
<?php
...
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexão,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE notification = 1");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        include 'sound.php';
        mysqli_query($this->conexão,"UPDATE pd_testes 
                                        SET Notificacao = 0;"); 
}
```

**sound.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="alerta.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero no está funcionando. ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?

Comment: Estas intentando que una tarea **cron**, que se ejecutado en un proceso  de background, intente lanzar un sonido como si se estuviera ejecutando en un navegador, lo cual **no es posible**.  Además tampoco sabes si el usuario que teoricamente debe recibir esa notificación sonora, tiene abierto el navegador, ni si eso lo ibas a mostrar en una nueva pestaña o en la misma que el estuviera usando que apunte a tu web.

Comment: Una posible solución sería que si el cron encuentra un nuevo pedido, guarde ese dato en algun archivo del sistema, y desde el código de tu página en el navegador, consultes si dicho archivo existe y en caso afirmativo lance ese sonido. Eso lo podrias hacer usando javascript y un temporizador que mediante ajax consulte a un script en PHP que verifique si existe el archivo y en caso afirmativo devuelva el dato al javascript y lanze el sonido. Pero el usuario debe estar en la página para oirlo, claro, pues se ejecuta desde el navegador.